# mysql batch insert : get the number of inserted lines

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, batch-insert

I'm using java to do batch inserts into a mysql table:

```
cnx = lconnect.openConnection();
mStatement = cnx.createStatement();
boolean firstTime = true;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

preparedStatement = cnx.prepareStatement(strQuery);
preparedStatement.setString(param1);
preparedStatement.setString(param2);
....
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.setString(param1);
preparedStatement.setString(param2);
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.setString(param1);
preparedStatement.setString(param2);

preparedStatement.execute();
```

Is there any way to really know the number of inserted lines ?

I think  my piece of code it's working (?) by the number of lines in the DB does not match with the number of lines supposed to be inserted, so I'm thinking I have a problem with y inserts maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [`executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29). The returned array contains the information you want.

From the JavaDoc:

> Returns:
>       an array of update counts containing one element for each command in the batch. The elements of the array are ordered according to the
>   order in which commands were added to the batch.

Comment: Oups. I had the wrong execute. I did noticed that there was an executeBatch(). Thanks alot. Solved my problem and all lines are now interted :). Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Use `PreparedStatement` object for each batch record :)